# How to remove duplicate alias hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, exception

I have this in my code for adding specific restrictions

```
criteria.createAlias("user", "user", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
```

But I get this error:

```
 queryException: dupliacate alias user
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You just can't use an alias name that is already an entity name. You can change this to

```
criteria.createAlias("user", "u", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
```

and then use the alias '**u**', e.g.

`.add( Restrictions.like("u.name", userName)`